# How to set chef data bag values via Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra

I posted "[How to set chef attributes via Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750087/how-to-set-chef-attributes-via-jenkins)" which was answered correctly, that is, using the "-j" option. However, what if I want to set the load version in the data bag in Jenkins so ALL cookbooks can use it? That is I don't want to use the "-j" option and instead search the value in the data bag? How do I do I set chef data bag values via Jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way: use knife commands to upload predfined or generated databags.

`knife data bag from file BAG json_file_for_item`

the file must have a defined format, extended documentation is [HERE](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_data_bags.html)

There's requirements on the file system hierarchy **and** on the file format, copying the doc here  sounds a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks. Say I already have a data bag with the load version definition. With your process, I'll have to keep changing the data bag to reflect the load version I want correct? I don't want to do this. I just want the data bag reflect what I pass via Jenkins

Comment: Jenkins may generate the json for you databag, we do that with a simple field replacement, the databag.json at first have placeholder like %%VERSION%% wich are replaced by the build task and the the updated databag is uploaded. You may do a `knife data bag show BAG ITEM -f json` to get the actual databag and set the placeholders

Answer (score 1):

In addition to knife, you can also write your own scripts using the Chef REST API. There are clients for Ruby (Chef-API), Python (PyChef), JavaScript (chef-js), and many others.